# Consulta Mysql Like no arroja resultados que contienen cero

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla que contiene este tipo de datos

| column [Varchar] |
| --- |
| 012345 |
| 051234 |
| 123456 |
| 145622 |

Al ejecutar la consulta

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colum LIKE '%5%'
```

Únicamente me arroja los resultados

123456
145622

No me arroja los que contienen los ceros, saben que pueda ser? o si estoy utilizando mal la sentencia? Gracias

Este es mi estructura que arroja phpmyadmin

```
--------------------------------------
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `unatabla` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unacolumna` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

ALTER TABLE `unatabla`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `unatabla`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
-------------------------------
```

Comment: El like le estas indicando que contenga el numero 5 , pero supongo que al tener indicada esa columna como varchar, a lo mejor no interpreta el cero como parte de esa cadena, intenta modificando  a un campo numérico: int, Tinyint u otro a lo mejor es eso.

Comment: Tu sentencia es correcta y no veo la forma o el porque en que pueda fallar tal como lo comentas.

Comment: Probé esto en [un fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae14b4/1/0) y se comporta como se espera. Debes incluir más información sobre la tabla (la sentencia CREATE que la define) para saber qué puede estar pasando

Comment: Añadí el Sql cuando exporto únicamente la estructura de la tabla @Alfabravo

Comment: Usar column como nombre de columna es pedir dolores de cabeza gratis. Está en las palabras reservadas y te toca usarlo siempre entre ticks como está en la creación que te muestra phpmyadmin [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L)

Comment: Cambia el nombre de la tabla y de la columna. Tanto TABLE como COLUMN son palabras reservadas. Empecemos por ahí...

Comment: si, solo es un ejemplo, tanto la tabla como la columna se llaman de manera diferente :D @JoelMuñozMoran

Comment: Lo siento, pero no se reproduce tu error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=0fba1a329e3a8da3d2df800ffaaa75d2